# setItem localStorage works fine but getItem localStorage doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I created a todo list that support modifying using content editable , I'm trying to make it store the created elements using localstorage

set localstorage works fine but doesn't save the editing using contenteditable , and the get local storage doesn't work at all inside or outside the event listener , can any body help & tell me what i'm missing ?

```js
   "use strict"

let todoInput = document.getElementById("todoInput");
let todoSubmit = document.getElementById("todoSubmit");
let todoList = document.getElementById("todoList");

var newTodoList = function newTodoList() {
 
  var todoItem = document.createElement("li");
  var todoItemSpan = document.createElement("span");
  var todoEdit = document.createElement("button");


  // Add classes to created elements
  todoItem.classList.add("todoItem");


  // add unique id to spans
  todoItemSpan.id = "id-" + Date.now();
  todoItem.id = "item-"  + Date.now();

  // add inner text to created elements
  todoItemSpan.innerText = todoInput.value;


  // add content editable and draggable
  todoItemSpan.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
  todoItem.setAttribute("draggable", true);

  /**------------------------------------
   * append children todoItem, todoItemSpan etc...
   ----------------------------------------*/

  todoList.appendChild(todoItem);
  todoItem.appendChild(todoItemSpan);

  /*------------------------------------
   save to local storage Works partly !!!
   -------------------------------------*/
   // set item works
  localStorage.setItem( todoItemSpan.id, todoItemSpan.innerHTML);
  
  //get item is not working here (inside addEventListener)
  document.getElementById(todoItemSpan.id).innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(todoItemSpan.id);

};

todoSubmit.addEventListener("click", newTodoList);

/*-----------------------------------
*get item is not working here neither (outside addEventListener)
*------------------------------------
document.getElementById(todoItemSpan.id).innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(todoItemSpan.id);
*/
```

```html
    <section id="todoWrap">
      <div class="todoHead">
        <h1>CRUD APP</h1>

        <div id="inputs">
          <input id="todoInput" type="text" name="" />
          <button id="todoSubmit">✔</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul id="todoList"></ul>
    </section>

    <script src="crud-list.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you hosting this on a server or opening the HTML file in your browser using the file:// protocol?

Comment: I use VSCODE live server addon

Answer (score 1):

`contenteditable` only allows the contents of the HTML element to be changed. It doesn't also change the value of any underlying data storage. You need to create a listener function attached to an event, likely `onChange`, for each `todoItemSpan`, that updates the relevant `localStorage` item.

Add this line at the end of the newTodoList function (possibly also rename to newTodoItem, which is a more accurate description)

```
  todoItemSpan.addEventListener('input', updateTodoItem);
```

This will run the `updateTodoItem` function for every change of the `contenteditable` TodoItemSpan, the code of which is below.

```
var updateTodoItem = function(e) {
  localStorage.setItem(e.target.id, e.target.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: my main problem is that even the (non-edited ) code is saved but when i call it using getItem nothing is called inside the main add event listener , i think the reason is that because that a refresh or open a new window won't trigger what's inside the "click" event listener so i tried outside it but i always get "todoItemSpan" is not defined

Comment: So what you want is the page showing the Todo Items stored in localStorage when you refresh or open the page? Again, this needs to be coded for. When the page loads, you need to read localStorage and create the TodoListItems.

Comment: thanks for responding , i tested that code and got an error
 Uncaught ReferenceError: todoItem is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.newTodoList

Comment: yes i'm trying to keep my todo items in place when i refresh or reopen the page

Answer (score 0):

so you're setting data under key 'ls'+todoItemSpan.id like

```
.setItem("ls" + todoItemSpan.id, todoItemSpan.innerHTML);
```

but then you're getting just todoItemSpan.id so missing that ls in front.

```
localStorage.getItem(todoItemSpan.id)
```

i recommend using a nice IDE (jetbrains?) that would highlight this kind of bugs.

Comment: thanks for responding , I trimmed that it doesn't work neither